# Firebase realtime updates for web, how to notice connection problems

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen to get realtime updates from my database in Firebase.

my code looks exactly like in the example:

```
db.collection("cities")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        //...
    }, function(error) {
        //...
    });
```

Sadly the error function is not called when the internet connection breaks. Does anyone know how to get notified when there is a connection problem to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Enabling Offline Capabilities in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities)

> Firebase applications work even if your app loses its network
>   connection temporarily. We provide several tools for monitoring
>   presence and synchronizing local state with server state, which are
>   introduced in this document.
>
> ```
> var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
> connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
>   if (snap.val() === true) {
>     alert("connected");
>   } else {
>     alert("not connected");
>   }
> });
> ```